# Is UFC Trainer only for right-handed people?

Tags: kinect, ufc-personal-trainer

I am trying to play UFC Trainer for Xbox 360 Kinect.  I am left handed, but it will only register my punches if I stand in a right-handed stance and throw my punches like a right-handed person.

Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 4):

The option to switch main hand is in the options menu, which is in the top left corner of the main page.